# how to encode and decode 64-bit format NTP timestamp?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, timestamp, ntp

I am trying encode and decode NTP timestamp (64-bit) format mentioned in **[RFC 5905 Section 6.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905#section-6)** 
Please explain me how to encode and decode 64-bit NTP timestamp with an example.

Comment: What language are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using C language to implement it, I understood that 64-bit NTP timestamp consists Seconds(32-bit)+Fraction(32-bit). I understood how to encode seconds field but I am not sure about it, and for the Fraction field I have no clue what or how it should be encoded.

Answer (score 2):

The open source [Apache Commons Net project](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) includes a Java implementation that encodes and decodes the NTP packet including the NTP 64-bit timestamp.

The NTP 64-bit timestamp is composed of 32-bits for the seconds field and 32-bits for the fractional seconds. The most significant bit (MSB) of seconds value defines the base date as 7-Feb-2036 if 0 or 1-Jan-1900 if 1.

The [TimeStamp class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-1.4.1/src-html/org/apache/commons/net/ntp/TimeStamp.html) encapsulates the conversion of [Java Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long)) (i.e., milliseconds since 1-Jan-1970 Epoch) to/from the NTP 64-bit representation. See TimeStamp.toNtpTime() and TimeStamp.getTime() methods. The encoding/decoding is straightforward to convert to C/C# or another language.

Comment: I need to decode the 128-bit NTP **Date**stamp field in C++, though I cannot find any implementions. I've problems decoding the *era number*. Apache Commons Net does not seem to provide an implementation for that... Any suggestions?

Comment: Wire format for 128-bit NTP format likewise in [RFC 5905 Section 6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5905#section-6)

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of the RFC. I am not able to calculate the *Era Number*, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421753/convert-boostposix-timeptime-to-ntp-datestamp