# Convert boost::posix_time::ptime to NTP datestamp

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, time, ntp

I need to convert a `boost::posix_time::ptime` into a NTP **Date**stamp according to
[RFC 5905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905) represented by the following structure:

```
struct NtpDatestamp {
  std::int32_t era_number;
  std::uint32_t seconds_since_era_epoch;
  std::uint64_t fraction_of_second;
};
```

RFC 5905 states the following:

> To convert system time in any format to NTP date and timestamp formats
> requires that the number of seconds `s` from the prime epoch to the system
> time be determined.  To determine the integer `era` and `timestamp` given `s`,
>
> ```
> era = s / 2^(32) and timestamp = s - era * 2^(32),
> ```
>
> which works for positive and negative dates.  To determine `s` given the era
> and timestamp,
>
> ```
> s = era * 2^(32) + timestamp.
> ```

Therefore I've tried the following:

```
const auto system_time = boost::posix_time::time_from_string("1899-12-31 00:00:00.000");

const boost::posix_time::ptime prime_epoch{boost::gregorian::date{1900, 1, 1}};
// Calculate the number of seconds from the prime epoch to the system time.
const boost::posix_time::time_duration time_duration{system_time - prime_epoch};
const std::int64_t s{time_duration.total_seconds()};
const std::int32_t era_number{static_cast<std::int32_t>(s / std::pow(2, 32))};
const std::uint64_t seconds_since_era_epoch{static_cast<std::uint64_t>(s - s / std::pow(2, 32) * std::pow(2, 32))};
// The fraction of a NTP Datestamp is measured in Attoseconds.
const std::uint64_t fraction_of_second{static_cast<std::uint64_t>(time_duration.total_microseconds() * 1e12)};
```

But that gives incorrect results.

I am completely stumped with this (actually simple) problem at the moment.

Can someone guide me into the correct direction? How can I obtain the *era number*, *era offset* and *fraction* of a NTP datestamp from a `boost::posix_time::ptime`?

**Edit:** Either the calculations in RFC 5905 are not accurate enough or I do misinterpret them. Thanks to the comments I've changed the calculation to the following (this time a complete example):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main() {
  const auto system_time =
      boost::posix_time::time_from_string("1899-12-31 00:00:00.000");

  const boost::posix_time::ptime prime_epoch{
      boost::gregorian::date{1900, 1, 1}};
  // Calculate the number of seconds from the prime epoch to the system time.
  const boost::posix_time::time_duration time_duration{prime_epoch -
                                                       system_time};

  // s is correctly determined now.
  std::int64_t s{time_duration.total_seconds()};
  if (prime_epoch > system_time) {
    // boost::posix_time::time_duration does not take the sign into account.
    s *= -1;
  }

  // TODO(wolters): The following calculations do not return the correct
  // results, but the RFC 5905 states them
  const std::int32_t era{static_cast<std::int32_t>(s / std::pow(2, 32))};
  const std::uint64_t timestamp{
      static_cast<std::uint64_t>(s - era * std::pow(2, 32))};
  // The fraction of a NTP Datestamp is measured in Attoseconds.
  // TODO(wolters): `boost::posix_time::ptime` does NOT resolve to attoseconds,
  // but doesn't the target format expect the value to be specified as
  // attoseconds? Doesn't the following depend on Boost compile options?
  const std::uint64_t fraction{
      static_cast<std::uint64_t>(time_duration.fractional_seconds())};

  std::cout << "s = " << std::dec << s << '\n';
  // TODO(wolters): This does still not match the expected results; taken from
  // Figure 4 of https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5905.txt
  std::cout << "Era (expected: -1) = " << std::dec << era << '\n';
  std::cout << "Timestamp (expected: 4294880896) = " << std::dec << timestamp
            << '\n';
  std::cout << "Fraction (expected: 0) = " << std::dec << fraction << '\n';
}
```

`s` is calculated correctly now, but the other calculations are wrong. I think I do miss something important completely...

Comment: one problem: seconds_since_era_epoch should compute s - era_number * 2^32, but the way you calculate it it will always be zero.

Comment: second problem: fraction_of_second should use time_duration.fractional_seconds()
third problem: ptime cannot resolve to attoseconds...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I've figured out the missing pieces by myself. I've implemented the following algorithm in a reusable class `ntp::Datestamp` and unit tested it with the reference dates of RFC 5905. All tests finally are green. Here is the solution:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

static std::time_t to_time(const boost::posix_time::ptime& time) {
  static const boost::posix_time::ptime epoch_time{
      boost::gregorian::date{1970, 1, 1}};
  const boost::posix_time::time_duration diff{time - epoch_time};

  return (diff.ticks() / diff.ticks_per_second());
}

int main() {
  const auto system_time =
      boost::posix_time::time_from_string("1899-12-31 00:00:00.123");
  const boost::posix_time::ptime prime_epoch{
      boost::gregorian::date{1900, 1, 1}};
  // Calculate the number of seconds from the prime epoch to the system time.
  std::time_t s{to_time(system_time) - to_time(prime_epoch)};

  const std::int32_t era{static_cast<std::int32_t>(std::floor(s / std::pow(2, 32)))};
  const std::uint32_t timestamp{
      static_cast<std::uint32_t>(s - era * std::pow(2, 32))};
  const std::uint64_t fraction{static_cast<std::uint64_t>(
      system_time.time_of_day().fractional_seconds())};

  std::cout << "s = " << std::dec << s << '\n';
  std::cout << "Era (expected: -1) = " << std::dec << era << '\n';
  std::cout << "Timestamp (expected: 4294880896) = " << std::dec << timestamp
            << '\n';
  std::cout << "Fraction (expected: 123000) = " << std::dec << fraction << '\n';
}
```